# Adding titles to xtable

Tags: r, sweave

I'm not sure if this is an R question or a Sweave question. I"m looking at students' marks from 2 time points in a simple table (Grade 3 and Grade 6). I've created the table and it prints, however I want to add labels so people know which mark is from which Grade.

My Sweave code is:

```
<<MakeData,results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
Grade3 <- c("A","B","B","A","B","C","C","D","A","B","C","C","C","D","B","B","D","C","C","D")
Grade6 <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","A","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D","D")
Cohort <- table(Grade3,Grade6)
print(xtable(Cohort))
@
```

I get a nice table with counts, however both rows and columns have the same notation. How do I add a label to make it clearer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To change the labels for `Cohort`, change the column and rownames:

```
rownames(Cohort) <- 1:4
colnames(Cohort) <- 5:8
```

You also add table titles to the `xtable` call:

```
print(xtable(Cohort, caption = 'My Title'), caption.placement = 'top')
```

You can use `caption.placement` to tell where to put the caption.

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments, I didn't answer the question above.  To make `xtable` print more like `table` with the labels above the levels, you use `add.to.row` in the `print.xtable` function:

```
addtorow <- list()
addtorow$pos <- list()
addtorow$pos[[1]] <- 0
addtorow$pos[[2]] <- 0
addtorow$command <- c('& & Grade 6 & & \\\\\n', "Grade 3 & A & B & C & D \\\\\n")
print(xtable(Cohort, caption = 'My Title'), caption.placement = 'top', 
      add.to.row = addtorow, include.colnames = FALSE)
```

`add.to.row` takes a list with two elements: `pos` and `command`.  `pos` is a list of whose length is the same as `command` which is a vector.  Each element of `pos` is the line in the table where you are placing the corresponding element of `command`.

Here, I want the first two lines to be where the labels go.  I set the first and second elements of `pos` to 0 to indicate that I am putting things on the top of the table.  The 0 position is that between the two horizontal rules in the table.

The `\\\\\n` produce the '\\' in the LaTeX code that is used at the end of each line of a table plus a newline character.

The help for `xtable` has a good example of `add.to.row` for more information.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for something in the pdf like the `Grade6` and `Grade3` that are included in what's printed to the R-console when you do `table(Grade3, Grade6)`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: thank you, I have updated the answer to better answer OPs question.

Comment: Nicely done. Extending your answer, this is even a bit better: `addtorow$command <- c('& \\multicolumn{4}{c}{Grade 6} \\\\\n', "Grade 3 & A & B & C & D \\\\\n")`.

Comment: Thanks all - Josh's line cleans up the table nicely.